# Handling exceptions thrown in a canceled Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm working through the examples in the [Exam Ref 70-483: Programming in C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DV6E4LG) book and have run into a problem with the following code from listing 1-44.  In this example, the author is trying to demonstrate that a continuation task has access to unhandled exceptions thrown in the antecedent task, and can handle them if it is appropriate to do so.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    Task task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        throw new OperationCanceledException();
    }, token).ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        t.Exception.Handle((e) => true);
        Console.WriteLine("You have canceled the task.");
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);

    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to stop the task.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    task.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to end the application.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Unfortunately, this line of code in the continuation

```
t.Exception.Handle((e) => true);
```

throws an exception because `t.Exception` is `null`.

Setting a breakpoint at that line, I can see that `t.Status` is `Canceled`, not `Faulted`.  Is this why the exception is not available?  What is the correct way to handle the exception thrown in the antecedent task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
task.ContinueWith(HandleError, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Cancelled tasks are not exceptional... And therefore will not include an exception. Faulted ones will.

Comment: So, if I want to keep the continuation option `OnlyOnCanceled`, the only way to handle that exception is within the first Task?

Comment: @adrift, No.  You can add another continuation that is `OnlyOnFaulted`

Comment: @MattSmith the second continuation catches the null ref exception thrown in the first continuation, not the exception thrown in the original task.  If I comment out the offending line in the first continuation, the second continuation is never entered.  That makes sense as it is a continuation of the first continuation.

Comment: @adrift, Don't make a continuation on the continuation--make it on the original task (i.e. add two continuations on the first task: one for faulted and one for Cancelled).  In the "on cancelled" one don't look at the Exception property because you know it will be null.  Look at the exception property in the faulted continuation.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code for Listing 1-44 to:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => { 
    while (true) 
    {
     token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
     Console.Write("*");
     Thread.Sleep(1000); }
    }, token).ContinueWith(t =>
 { Console.WriteLine("You have canceled the task"); }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
```